# Changing default subnet for docker custom networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Our internal network has the range 172.20.0.0/16 reserved for internal purposes and docker uses the 172 range by default for its internal networking. I can reset the bridge to live in 192.168 by providing the `bip` setting to the daemon:

```
➜  ~ sudo cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "bip": "192.168.2.1/24"
}

➜  ~ ifconfig                        
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
```

However, when creating new custom networks via `docker network create` or by defining them in the `networks` sections of the `docker-compose.yaml` these are still created in 172, thus eventually clashing with `172.20`:

```
➜  ~ docker network create foo
610fd0b7ccde621f87d40f8bcbed1699b22788b70a75223264bb14f7e63f5a87
➜  ~ docker network inspect foo | grep Subnet
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
➜  ~ docker network create foo1              
d897eab31b2c558517df7fb096fab4af9a4282c286fc9b6bb022be7382d8b4e7
➜  ~ docker network inspect foo1 | grep Subnet
                "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
```

I understand I can provide the subnet value to `docker network create`, but I rather want all such subnets created under `192.168.*`.

How can one configure `dockerd` to do this automatically?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For anyone who found this question. Now it is possible.

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
```

Edit or create config file for docker daemon:

```
# nano /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Add lines:

```
{
  "default-address-pools":
  [
    {"base":"10.10.0.0/16","size":24}
  ]
}
```

Restart dockerd:

```
# service docker restart
```

Check the result:

```
$ docker network create foo
$ docker network inspect foo | grep Subnet
                    "Subnet": "10.10.1.0/24"
```

It works for docker-compose too.

Your `"bip": "192.168.2.1/24"` works for bridge0 only. It means that any container which run without `--network` will use this default network.

Comment: Does this work with networks generated by `docker-compose` also? Probably not?

Comment: Dude, why it is /16 with a size of 24?

Comment: @Obay Abd-Algader docker will create a "pool" of 10.10.0.0/16. Each subnet will then take /24 out of the pool.

Comment: Thanks, I got it @anch2150. Also I noticed that old networks stay there unless removed manually.

Comment: Confirming that this works with Docker Desktop in Windows as well. Just add this config by opening the GUI and navigating to Settings>Docker Engine> Add this text as an entry inside the {} outer braces, then click the Apply& Restart button at the bottom.