# How to work around clash of Docker network interfaces with public WiFi hotspots

Tags: docker, networking, ip, wifi, hotspot

On a regular basis my Docker networks clash with public WiFi hotspots which seem to run on the same IP address space resulting in me being unable to get to the registration page.

I then have to manually shutdown the Docker service and delete every network interface by hand. Is there a better, more sustainable solution?

Comment: Suffering from the same problem. I usually use `docker network prune`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing default subnet for docker custom networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003663/changing-default-subnet-for-docker-custom-networks)