# How to configure KOPS to designate a CIDR other than 172.17 for Docker?

Tags: kops

`kops create` by default sets up a 172.17.0.0/16 for the Docker network (docker0 interface). This conflicts with our VPC in AWS which uses the same CIDR.

I need KOPS to designate a different CIDR for docker when creating the cluster, but I''m not seeing where to do this. What's the procedure for telling KOPS to configure a different CIDR for Docker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing default subnet for docker custom networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003663/changing-default-subnet-for-docker-custom-networks)

Comment: @Jonnix My question is how to do this with kops (kops is a wrapper which takes care of configuring all the components of a k8s cluster, including the docker component).

Answer (score 0):

When creating a cluster using `kops create cluster`, you can provide the flag `--network-cidr` for customising the CIDR of the VPC.

[Reference](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_create_cluster.md)

Comment: --network-cidr is for the kubernetes nodes, not the docker subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bridgeIP(bip) in kops cluster config file under spec -> docker:

```
spec:
  docker:
    bridgeIP: 192.168.208.1/24
```

Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/pkg/apis/kops/dockerconfig.go#L26

If you are creating from scratch, above should work, if you are updating this config in existing kops managed cluster, you should include `logDriver` options, otherwise, it will leads to crash or unexpected behavior. Refer below

```
 docker:
   bridgeIP: 192.168.208.1/24
   logDriver: json-file
```

Reference: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/5336#issuecomment-397604114