# Unable to reach host VPN from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm connected to a VPN in my host (**Docker for Windows**) and when I try to ping an endpoint behind the VPN from docker container in network=bridge or network=host mode I get the following error:

```
root@linux:/# ping 172.XX.XX.X
From 172.XX.XX.X icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Host ipconfig

```
Windows IP configuration

VEthernet Ethernet Adapter (Pre Modifier):

   Specific DNS suffix for the connection. . :
   Link: local IPv6 address. . . : fe70 :: adaf2: d383d1b8% 27
   IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.11.123.225
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . :

Ethernet ethernet adapter (DockerNAT):

   Specific DNS suffix for the connection. . :
   IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . :

Wi-Fi wireless LAN adapter:

   IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.178.1.14
   Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Docker container (ubuntu) ifconfig:

```
root@linuxki:/# ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe8223::42:dtff:fe62:f670  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 01:30:dc:62:d6:551  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 168 (168.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.65.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.65.255
        inet6 fedtrss0::50:fqws:fe00:1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:50:00:10:03432:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 66298  bytes 96432923 (96.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23123  bytes 1318183 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

hvint0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.75.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:febc:e103  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:45:5d:jc:e1:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 857  bytes 142179 (142.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 8  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18  bytes 1408 (1.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20  bytes 1900 (1.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 1900 (1.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried with `docker run--net host [...]` instead of bridge?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33913291/6482759) is a solution that might help. If not, please post the output of `ipconfig` in Windows and that of `ifconfig` in the container.

Comment: I haved tried that solution and still did not work. I added the host ipconfig @bellackn

Comment: What IP does your container have, and in what network is it spawned? Also, what's the output of `docker inspect your_container`? I'm not familiar with Docker on Windows, but I'll try my best here.

Comment: Update the post with container info @bellackn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192845/discussion-between-bellackn-and-rafael-reyes).

Comment: Well what happened in the chat ???? Did we get a solution ?