# Unable to make Docker container use OpenConnect VPN connection

Tags: docker, vpn, openconnect

I have a VM running Ubuntu 16.04, on which I want to deploy an application packaged as a Docker container. The application needs to be able to perform an HTTP request towards a server under VPN (e.g. `server1.vpn-remote.com`)

I successfully configured the host VM in order to connect to the VPN through `openconnect`, I can turn this connection on/off using a `systemd` service.

Unfortunately, when I run `docker run mycontainer`, neither the host nor the container are able to reach `server1.vpn-remote.com`. Weirdly enough, there is no error displayed in the VPN connection service logs, which is stuck to the openconnect messages confirming a successful connection.

If I restart the VPN connection after starting `mycontainer`, the host machine is able to access  `server1.vpn-remote.com`, but not the container. Moreover, if I issue any command like `docker run/start/stop/restart` on `mycontainer` or any other container, the connection gets broken again even for the host machine.

NOTE: I already checked on the ip routes and there seems to be no conflict between Docker and VPN subnets.

NOTE: running the container with `--net="host"` results in both host and container being able to access the VPN but I would like to avoid this option as I will eventually make a docker compose deployment which requires all containers to run in bridge mode.

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: I figured out it is a DNS issue, as I'm able to ping the IP corresponding to `server1.vpn-remote.com` even after the VPN connection seemed to be failing. I'm going through documentation regarding DNS management with Docker and Docker Compose and their usage of the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you don't still need help six months later! Some of the details are different, but this sounds a bit like a problem I had. In my case the solution was a bit disappointing: after you've connected to your VPN, restart the docker daemon:

`sudo systemctl restart docker`

I'm making some inferences here, but it seems that, when the daemon starts, it makes some decisions/configs based on the state of the network at that time. In my case, the daemon starts when I boot up. Unsurprisingly, when I boot up, I haven't had a chance to connect to the VPN yet. As a result, my container traffic, including DNS lookups, goes through my network directly.

Hat tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61498726/1828069) for guiding me down the correct path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The way I worked it around was by setting the `docker run` [--dns flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings), with the VPN's  DNS server address. I honestly don't remember whether I had tried your solution already but didn't work for some reason, or not.

Comment: Your answer helped. Thanks.